# Get any differentiater key for Shopify Product update and create an order

Tags: shopify, shopify-api

Shopify sends webhook of 'product-update' in both cases- Updating a product and creating an Order. On creating orders, product quantity is deducted from 1st location mentioned as per location fulfillment priority.
My problem is-

1. I want to differentiate 'product-update' webhook such that is it coming due to updating the product OR creating an order.
2. Is there any way in shopify REST API to get the locations as per fulfillment priorities?

Thanks,

Comment: are you sure there is the same webhooks, you need to check it into documentation, there are separates webhook mentioned for orders and products, I think you doing wrong [check  here](https://shopify.dev/docs/admin-api/rest/reference/events/webhook)

Comment: I have verified this. Create any order and you will get product/update webhook too, with order/create.

Comment: I think you need to ask the same into Shopify community forum, or with Shopify support regarding and make sure is it work like it or something buggy [Forum Link](https://community.shopify.com/c/Shopify-APIs-SDKs/bd-p/shopify-apis-and-technology)